# Windows 7 Networking issue

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 7 desktop and the only way I can get it on my network is to disable and then enable the network card.  This works fine until I have to restart/turn on the computer.  It has been this way since I installed Windows.  I have done the normal fix-it with deleting the card/network and re-installing.

Not sure what else to try...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see if the card's manufacturer has specific drivers available to download.  Windows can install drivers for most cards, but I've had cards that would not work unless I got the manufacturer's driver.  You could also try setting the card with a static IP address instead of allowing it to receive one from your router (or other DHCP source).